# Find and delete duplicated entries in different .txt files and create one file

Tags: ubuntu, terminal, createfile

I have an **Ubuntu** Desktop. There is a folder with 90 **.txt** or **.dic** files. Now I have to create one huge .txt file with all 90 files and without duplicates.

Example:
-wordlist1.txt
-wordlist2.txt
-wordlist3.txt
-names1.dic
-names2.dic

At the end I need 1 **TOTAL.txt** file.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please [take the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour), have a look around, and read through the help center, in particular [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). What part are you stuck on? What have you tried? Right now, the question reads like "please write code for me to do this" which presumably isn't what you mean.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest Python, but in all languages you should do something like this:

```
open output file
for each file in folder
    open file
    for each line in current file
        if line not in array_lines
             write line to output file
             add line to array_lines
    close file
close output file
```

I suggest Python because it's very good with text files and you can actually write something like "if line not in array_lines" and it will work... It's very similar to this pseudo-code.

Comment: Thank you very much. I found a another solution. I just made one huge .txt file and then used the sort -u command to delete dublicates. I had to wait like 20 hours, but it worked.